# explode only the first '='

Tags: php, explode

I need to explode a .txt file with a lot of lines, these lines are described like this:

```
achievements.levelup.desc=You unlocked the Achievement
achievements.levelup.ok=OK
achievements.levelup.reward=Reward: <b><font size="30" color="#7adde9">%amount%</font></b> %currency_name%
```

Now that the problem is, is the second and third `=` inside the third line.

It is that it's also exploding on those `=` es.

How i'm now exploding, is like this:

```
<?php
$array = explode("=", $data, 2);
?>
```

UPDATE: added more code

INDEX.php

```
<?php
require_once('reader.class.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>External Variables Uitlezen</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <br><br>
    <br><br>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <label>Hoeveel rijen wil je zien?</label>
        <input type="number" name="amount">
        <input type="submit" name="enterRows" value="Verder">
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <hr>
    <br><br>
    <?php
    $fileName = "external_flash_texts.txt";
    $extReader = new Ext_Var($fileName);
    $extReader->SetContent();
    if (!isset($_POST['opslaan']) && empty($_POST['opslaan'])) {
        if (isset($_GET['enterRows']) && !empty($_GET['enterRows'])) {
            echo '<form action="" method="post">';
            echo $extReader->GetContent($_GET['amount']);
            echo '<input type="submit" name="opslaan" value="Opslaan">';
            echo '</form>';
        } else {
            echo '<form action="" method="post">';
            echo $extReader->GetContent(10);
            echo '<input type="submit" name="opslaan" value="Opslaan">';
            echo '</form>';
        }
    } else {
        $extReader->Save($_POST);
    }
    ?>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

reader.class.php

```
<?php
class Ext_Var {
    //File info
    private $_fName;
    private $_fHandler;
    //File content
    private $_content = [];
    //New file content
    private $_newContent;
    //Read file
    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->_fName = $file;
        $this->_fHandler = fopen($this->_fName, "r");
    }
    public function SetContent() {
        while ($data = fgets($this->_fHandler)) {
            $array = explode("=", $data, 2);
            $this->_content[$array[0]] = $array[1];
        }
    }
    public function GetContent($caller) {
        $counter = 1;
        $content = "";
        foreach ($this->_content as $field => $value) {
            if ($counter <= $caller) {
                $content .= "<p><label>" . $field . "</label> = <input type='text' name='" . $field . "' value='" . $value . "'></p>";
                $counter++;
            }
        }
        return $content;
    }
    public function Save($array) {
        if (isset($array) && !empty($array)) {
            foreach($this->_content as $field => $value) {
                if (isset($array["$field"]) && !empty($array["$field"])) {
                    $this->_newContent .= $field . "=" . $array["$field"] . "\n";
                } else {
                    $this->_newContent .= $field . "=" . $value;
                }
            }
            if (file_put_contents($this->_fName, $this->_newContent)) {
                header("Location: ?msg=Succes");
            } else {
                echo 'fout';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: how you read  le file ? ... show the code  please

Comment: And your problem? What is the resulting array like?

Comment: Hmm the `$array` I get doing things the way you did seems fine. There must be a misunderstanding. What do you `$array` to be?

Comment: `$array = explode("=", $data);` why do you not put the **limit 2** _(3rd parameter)_ there?

Comment: @Mihailo What do you mean/.

Comment: You've updated you post with ALL the code. Inside **reader.class.php** I found what I mentioned above, inside the while loop inside the `SetContent()` method.

Comment: @Mihailo I Ment do I need to put a 3 instead of a 2?

Comment: @ChickenWing1996 also no need to call isset() && !empty(); !empty() is enough and if (isset($array) && !empty($array)) { -> if($array){ also the convention for function naming is using camelCase; setContent() instead SetContent()

Comment: @ChickenWing1996 are you hungry? Your code. Does not have. `$array = explode("=", $data, 2);` Like you've said it should. If the code you've posted is your actual code add the limit to the explode function.

Comment: @Mihailo oops sorry, I posted the older 1 xD, from github

Comment: @Mihailo Updated!

Comment: Ok cool. What does the `$array` return after you explode the `$data` `die(var_dump(`$array`))` right after you make the explosion.

Comment: @Mihailo A BIG BIG ARRAY! :S

Comment: @ChickenWing1996 BIG ARRAYS ! Ok so are you sure `$this->_fHandler` does the job correctly? What do you get when you `die(var_dump($data));` before the explosion?

Comment: @Mihailo Yes i'm realy sure those things are correct cus it works! It is just that when `=` will be used in the value, it is going wrong

Comment: @ChickenWing1996 Ok I have to go now, but I'm pretty sure `explode()` is doing its job correctly, the string it gets from the `fgets()` is probably wrong. I still don't know if you're hungry though :[

Answer (score 1):

I'd have thought the obvious and simple way would be to work on each line separately and only then explode on `=`, using the `$limit` parameter set to `2`, which means that it will only split on the first `=`.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $data);
$settings = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $settings[] = explode("=", $line, 2);
}
```

You will now have an array like:

```
array(
    array(
        'achievements.levelup.desc',
        'You unlocked the Achievement'
    ),
    array(
        'achievements.levelup.ok',
        'OK'
    ),
    array(
        'achievements.levelup.reward'
        'Reward: <b><font size="30" color="#7adde9">%amount%</font></b> %currency_name%'
    )
)
```

This will of course only work if all your values are only on one line. If you have line breaks, then you are into a whole more complicated world of parsing and you probably need to build some kind of tokeniser.